# Meta refresh tag not executing after screen saver in IE11 metro mode

Tags: html, windows, internet-explorer-11

Just wondering if there is anything documented or anyone has information on why when using IE11 metro mode after screensaver goes on, meta tags on my webpage aren't executing.

Using this meta tag below in an html page & with your windows machine screensaver set to 1 minute open your webpage.

```
<META http-equiv="refresh" content="61;URL=http://www.google.com">
```

What happens in the desktop mode, is as expected: screen saver goes on, and meta tag is executed, browser navigates to www.google.com and when you exit the screensaver your webpage is still on www.google.com. However in metro mode, when you exit the screen saver you will be on the original page with that meta tag.

So is this a behavior that is documented? Anyone have a clue as to why this happens?

Comment: I wouldn't have a clue as to why this would happen, but in what scenario would you do a refresh to google after spending 1 minute on a webpage? And what user would have set their screensaver to one minute, while visiting this page? (And have their IE11 in metro mode). Just curious because this scenario seems very unlikely to me.

Comment: Very unlikely this would ever happen, probably never has and never will unless someone is testing the behavior of the browser, like me. It's just a small quirk that I noticed that I would like to know the reason behind.

And the navigation to google is just to simplify the problem for people reading this question, my redirection is to a different page on the same domain.